# Get all css styles that is used on a web page with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, styles, file-get-contents

I would just like to know if it would be possible to somehow get all the css code that is used for one web page using PHP.

If you have any ideas or suggestions, pleas tell me!

Thanks

Comment: php is server side, that means it can output any css you would like and totally control the page.  is your css in an external file?  if so javascript is what you're looking for.

Comment: @tq Yes, my css is in external files.. Guess youre right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the inspector of Google Chrome.

Just Right-Click > Inspect Element.

go to the sources tab and there you can see all the JS, CSS Files.